# Nuget WebRTC for UWP

Tags: windows-runtime, windows-10, uwp, webrtc, windows-10-universal

I am using nuget ["WebRTC for UWP"](https://www.nuget.org/packages/WebRTC/) and have one problem. 
So, I want make video call and I should :

1. Create offer (sdp)
2. Send offer
3. Another client receive offer and generate answer ans send to first
4. Call starts

If first client haven't camera (video device) it will generate offer (sdp) only for audio so call can't be with video from start :( 
How I can ignore this step and generate for video to, but only to one way?

UPD: My code for creating peer connection:

```
var configuration = new RTCConfiguration();
 configuration.IceServers = this.GetIceServers();
 this.PeerConnection = new RTCPeerConnection(configuration);
 this.LocalStream = await RtcManager.Instance.Media.GetUserMedia(new                
            RTCMediaStreamConstraints
            {
                videoEnabled = true,
                audioEnabled = true
            });

 this.PeerConnection.AddStream(this.LocalStream);

 var sessionOfferDescription = await this.PeerConnection.CreateOffer();
```

`sessionOfferDescription` variable has `Sdp` property and this property contains only audio: "a=group:BUNDLE audio"

Comment: If you want to receive video, tell the lib so by using "offerToReceiveVideo : true" in your constraints when creating the peerconnection. This works perfectly, even when not adding a video stream to the connection, the remote side will still send a video stream (if added on that side). Setting offerToReceiveAudio and/or offerToReceiveVideo to true combined with adding the streams on the remote side cause the stream to be sent, regardless of having added the streams on the local side.

Comment: @Kevin, thanks, but in this lib I didn't find these properties (`offerToReceiveVideo` and `offerToReceiveAudio`). Did you mean current nuget, that I wrote in the question?

Comment: I'm not talking about your specific implementation, WebRTC uses a constraints parameter when setting up the peerconnection. You can pass in an array of connection constraints for your connection, offerToReceiveVideo and offerToReceiveAudio are simply keys that you can use to create your connection. It's quite hard to help you further if you don't provide any code, don't explain what you already tried and what went wrong...

Comment: @Kevin, sorry, but I think that any code can't help you, because I haven't library code.  I added code to answer

Comment: Seems alright, are you sure you don't receive video when you setup the connection like this? When your offer-answer sequence is done, does onAddStream get called on the caller side? Do you call addStream on the callee side? Have you added a videotrack to the stream before adding it on the callee side? Ignore what is in your offer SDP, that's not important. Just check if you correctly add the stream and if onAddStream is called.

Comment: @Kevin, 
_>are you sure you don't receive video when you setup the connection like this?_ - Yes. Event `onAddStream` occurred but `GetVideoTracks` method returns empty collection.

 _>Do you call addStream on the callee side?_ - Did you mean receiver side or caller? Caller can't add video stream because he hasn't camera. On the receiver side - yes, I do.

Comment: And I create `LocalStream` (in receiver side) after creating `PeerConnection` and before set offer and generate answer AND LocalStream HAS video tracks

Comment: Yes callee means receiving side (the one "being called"). I can't figure out what's wrong then. Your case should be something like: caller creates peerconnection, caller creates offer, send offer to callee, callee creates peerconnection, callee creates answer, send answer to caller. onAddStream should now be called on caller side with a remote video track. Keep in mind though, onAddStream is also called when adding your local media, make sure you are checking the remote video track when it's called the second time (when SDP negotiation is done).

Comment: @Kevin, I recheck and I sure that it is RemoteStream, not local

Comment: I'm out of ideas then, sorry :(